# Can not connect to working webservice using android device

Tags: android

I used android device to connect via `wifi` to localhost of my computer.This is the string i m passing to retrieve values from web service.

I get a error message in logcat `OSNEtworkSystem_Connect fail:Timeout`. Can any one sugest a solution please.

```
String tabledata = getServerData[a link]("http://10.0.2.2:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?      FromSt='"+frm+"'"+" ToSt= '" +t+ "'"+" FromTime= '" +t01+ "' "+"ToTime='"+t02+ "'"+" ArriveTime= '" +at+ "'"+" DepartTime= '" +dt+ "'"+" ReachingTime= '" +rt+ "'"+" TrainId= '"+tid+"'" )[a link];


private String getServerData(String url) {// requet and response happens here
    String data = null;

    try {
        // Send GET request to <service>/GetPlates
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        // Read response data into buffer
        char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity.getContentLength()];
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));

        stream.close();

        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
        data = (String) o.get("d");
        System.out.println(data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return data;
}
```

after changing ip in to pc ip connection timeout eror is gone. now im gettin this error.
[image: log cat showing error]

Comment: This is the link for get server data --String tabledata = getServerData("http://10.0.2.2:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?FromSt='"+frm+"'"+" ToSt= '" +t+ "'"+" FromTime= '" +t01+ "' "+"ToTime='"+t02+ "'"+" ArriveTime= '" +at+ "'"+" DepartTime= '" +dt+ "'"+" ReachingTime= '" +rt+ "'"+" TrainId= '"+tid+"'" );

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `10:0:2:2` to connect to devices. you need to provide PC's IP address when trying the application on real device.

follow the steps:

1- go to CMD and type `ipconfig`.

2- Search for IPv4 and copy the address.

3- use it in your code.. this is an example of how it should look like:

```
http://192.168.0.106:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?.... // you must have similar IP to this.
```

4-  **Turn off the firewall and any anti-virus program**

hope this will make your application work in a real device. please give me a feedback of what will happen

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. actually i used a virtual router and as you said i changed ip address in to my pc address. Now Connection timeout error is gone. But im getting this errors in log cat and cannot retrieve data. Can you please help me on that.Iadded it in question.tnx.

Comment: can you give us the value of `t` `t01`, `t02, ... I want to check if the site is accessible from a PC. so we know whether the problem from the server or from the android.

Comment: Actualy it is a local host.Web service is working.It is giving values. I only used variable "frm" with a value.(a string value). Other values are send as null. i only use those variables to get values.but couldn't retrieve data to andriod device.

Comment: what is the localhost you are using? XAMPP?! also can you add the PHP script so we know how you are receiving the data.

Comment: also, did you make sure that you turned off the firewall and anti-virus in your computer because they want allow any device to have access to your PC

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean connect localhost via wi-fi

- instal a virtual router to your computer. Then via wi-fi connect to your computer with your mobile device.

here is a link for  [virtual router](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)

- when you install it, connect with your mobile device to that virtual wi-fi provider. probably the ip that you should connect will be
- `http://192.168.1.1:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?` something(to
  learn it open cmd-forwindowns enter `ipconfig` to learn the router device's
  ip.

Be careful if you have internet connection

- there will be two major ip addresses one is for your
  computer that as a client to connect to the internet,
- the other one is for the virtual router as a servise host which you need to connect connect

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. actually i used a virtual router and as you said i changed ip address in to my pc address. Now Connection timeout error is gone. But im getting this errors in log cat and cannot retrieve data. Can you please help me on that.Iadded it in question.tnx.

Comment: is `http://192.168.173.1:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?(with parameter)` works in your internet browser?

Comment: can u please explain how to add parameters when using in internet browser relevant to my link to get data. Anyway I debug and didnt get values to String tabledata.can u suggest a solution.thnks

Comment: pass parameter if needed. What parameters does your service requires to response? (add them to your question). if it does not required then remove `?` from the request link then try.

Comment: i m passing only a string value.i set it as -- http://192.168.173.1:52764/Service1.asmx/getTrainTimeTable?Maradana --but it didn't work. how to set that string value in the link in the browser.can u pls explain?

Comment: .....Table?maradanahow="yourstring", if do not get any response then you have a problem with your service

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41339/discussion-between-user1247819-and-ismail)